# How to run demo "hello world" android app in ubuntu 14.0?

Tags: java, android

I am new in android development .Actually i am trying to run simple "hellow world" android app in eclipse i am getting error in mainactivity.java so i am not able to run this demo app in eclipse.

so any one can help me please.

[image]

console:

```
[2014-06-11 21:05:51 - adb] Unexpected exception 'Cannot run program "/home/himanshu/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory' while attempting to get adb version from '/home/himanshu/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools/adb'
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your Stack Trace. As a basic for all "find my error" questions, providing information on where the error _occurs_ is a necessity.

Comment: [2014-06-11 21:05:51 - adb] Unexpected exception 'Cannot run program "/home/himanshu/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory' while attempting to get adb version from '/home/himanshu/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools/adb'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the SDK manager and make sure you install all of the SDK relevant files and the emulator relevant files. Look through your SDK manager and tell me if that worked. If you are not sure what to do with the SDK manager once it is opened, comment this, and I will help you out.

Comment: Thanks for reply Actually i am download adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321 file and run it .but i am not install any sdk relevant files .can you tell me please which file i install before run this app